# "value_counts" for each row pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have `pandas` dataframe of the form:

```
       Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
 0      1      2       2     1       2
 1      2      2       1     1       1
 2      2      2       2     2       2
 3      1      1       1     1       2
 4      1      2       2     1       1
```

Now, I want to add two more columns to this dataframe such that the new columns - `num` and `count` refer to the number that occurs the most in the row and its count respectively i.e.:

```
       Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   count   num
 0      1      2       2     1       2     3       2
 1      2      2       1     1       1     3       1
 2      2      2       2     2       2     5       2
 3      1      1       1     1       2     4       1
 4      1      2       2     1       1     3       1
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get most occurence value by [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html), compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and count `True` values by `sum`, last create new columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
m = df.mode(axis=1)[0]
df = df.assign(count=df.eq(m, axis=0).sum(axis=1), num=m)
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  count  num
0     1     2     2     1     2      3    2
1     2     2     1     1     1      3    1
2     2     2     2     2     2      5    2
3     1     1     1     1     2      4    1
4     1     2     2     1     1      3    1
```

Another idea with custom function, but because `apply` is loop under the hood solution should be slowier if large DataFrame:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.value_counts()
    return pd.Series([x.index[0], x.iat[0]])
df[['count','num']] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```